# What if a tzitzit string gets dyed?

Tags: tzitzis

If a tzitzit string accidentally gets dyed (yellow, or purple, or orange etc.) on a regular white beged, is it kosher or pasul?

Comment: It is kosher, there is a discussion though of the beged needs to be same color